# Can you debug swc in flash builder

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, swc

Can you debug and step through the code of a swc files in flash builder?

Let's say you even have access to source code (coming from flex library project or flash professional project)! If how?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, though there are some limitations (as FlashBuilder will tell you when you do it), but simple stepping is no problem.

If you have the source code in a project in FlashBuilder, FB should find the associated code automatically. If you don't you can associate the source code to the swc manually. Go to the Flex Build Path window; click on the arrow next to the swc; double click the row that says "Source attachment" and enter the path to the source code.

[image]

Comment: awesome... it was a trimmed down version of my original question which was kinda complicated and confusing, I admit, your answer solved a bigger picture, please post the url of this page as an answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10554016/debugging-flex-and-php-project-with-flash-professional-in-flash-builder#comment13659879_10554016 so I can give you credit there as well. Thanks. :)